# How to pass using delegates in a tableview through the footer cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, delegates

What Im trying to do is pass data to another view controller through a button in the CalorieFooter cell using a Delegate to pass data in the cell.

I can't successfully pass data through the infoButton in the **CalorieFooter** cell to show the fat, carbs, and proteins for the calorie consumption of that day in the CalorieBreakdownController.

I am currently getting "0"'s in all labels of the CalorieBreakdownController (as seen in the far right of the image).

I think the issue might be because my ***calculationDelegate*** is done in the CalorieFooter cell. and the way I got the subtotal in the cell was by seperating the cells into sections. im a little confused at how to pass data to CalorieBreakdownController from the the footer, to get the "Subtotal" in the labels.

How would I be able to pass the "subTotal" data the CalorieBreakdownController from the calorieFooter cell (as seen in the image below)

thanks in advance for any help that is provided
[image: CalorieTotal]

```
 import UIKit

 class CalorieViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedFood: FoodList!
    var additionalCalories: DailyCalories!                  // delegate code for footer

    var calorieItems: [DailyCalories] = []
    var groupedCalorieItems: [String: [DailyCalories]] = [:]
    var dateSectionTitle: [DailyCalories] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var calorieTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        groupedFoodItems = Dictionary(grouping: calorieItems, by: {$0.foodList.day})
        dateSectionTitle = groupedCalorieItems.map{$0.key}.sorted()

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if let vc = segue.destination as? CalorieTotalController {   // delegate code for footer
            vc.additionalCalories = self.additionalCalories
        }
    }
}

extension CalorieViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dateSectionTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let date = dateSectionTitle[section]
        return groupedCalorieItems[date]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let calorieCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalorieCell") as! CalorieCell

        let date = dateSectionTitle[indexPath.section]
        let calorieItemsToDisplay = groupedCalorieItems[date]![indexPath.row]
        calorieCell.configure(withCartItems: calorieItemsToDisplay.foodList)

        return calorieCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let calorieHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalorieHeader") as! CalorieHeader

        let headerTitle = dateSectionTitle[section]
        calorieHeader.dateLbl.text = "Date: \(headerTitle)"

        return calorieHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let calorieFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalorieFooter") as! CalorieFooter

        let date = dateSectionTitle[section]
        let arrAllItems = groupedCalorieItems[dispensary]!
        var subtotal: Float = 0
        for item in arrAllItems {
            if item.foodList.selectedOption == 1 {
                 subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.foodList.calorie1) * Float(item.foodList.count))
            } else if item.foodList.selectedOption == 2 {
                 subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.foodList.calorie2) * Float(item.foodList.count))
            } else if item.foodList.selectedOption == 3 {
                 subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.foodList.calorie3) * Float(item.foodList.count))
            }
        }

        calorieFooter.cartTotal.text = "\(subtotal)"
        calorieFooter.calculationDelegate = self                  // delegate code for footer
        calorieFooter.additionalCalories! = ???                   // can't get the right code set to allow the data to pass
        calorieFooter.calculations! = ???                         // can't get the right code set to allow the data to pass
        return calorieFooter
    }  
}

extension CalorieViewController: CalculationDelegate {     // delegate code for footer
    func onTouchInfoButton(from cell: CalorieFooter) {
        self.additionalCalories = cell.additionalCalories
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CalculateDailyCalorieCell", sender: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

protocol CalculationDelegate: class {                     // delegate code for footer
    func onTouchInfoButton(from cell: CalorieFooter)
}

class CalorieFooter: UITableViewCell {

    weak var calculationDelegate: CalculationDelegate?   // delegate code for footer
    var additionalCalories: DailyCalories!                            // delegate code for footer
    var calculations: [DailyCalories] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var calorieTotal: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var additionalFeesBtn: UIButton!


    @IBAction func overallTotalBtn(_ sender: Any) {
         self.additionalFeesDelegate?.onTouchInfoButton(from: self)   // delegate code for footer
    }
}
```

---

```
class CalorieTotalController: UIViewController {

    var additionalCalories: DailyCalories!             // delegate code for footer
    var calculations: [DailyCalories] = []            // delegate code for footer

    @IBOutlet weak var calorieSubtotal: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var fatTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var carbTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var proteinTotal: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // calculations done for when data is passed through Delegate
        var subtotal: Float = 0
        for item in calculations {
            if item.foodList.selectedOption == 1 {
                 subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.foodList.calorie1) * Float(item.foodList.count))
            } else if item.foodList.selectedOption == 2 {
                 subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.productList.calorie2) * Float(item.foodList.count))
            } else if item.foodList.selectedOption == 3 {
                 subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.foodList.calorie3) * Float(item.foodList.count))
            }
        }

        let protein = Float(subtotal * 0.25)
        let carbs = Float(subtotal * 0.25)
        let fat = Float(subtotal * 0.5)

        calorieSubtotal.text = String(subtotal!)
        proteinTotal.text = String(protein!)
        fatTotal.text = String(fat!)
        carbTotal.text = String(carbs!)

    }

    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Calories BreakDown")
    }    
}
```

Comment: where is `calorieFooter.additionalCalories`  ?

Comment: @AndresGomez I didn't put it in, because no matter what ive tried I kept getting a error code in it

Comment: ```cartFooter.additionalCosts! = arrAllItems``` ive used this but I always get the error "Cannot assign value of type '[DailyCalories]' to type 'DailyCalories' " similar to how I have my cellForRowAt set

Comment: You are setting `additionalCalories` in `CalorieTotalController` in your `prepare(for segue: ...)` func, but you are not ***using*** `additionalCalories` anywhere in `CalorieTotalController`. In addition, you ***are*** using `calculations`, but you are ***not*** setting it. In `CalorieViewController`, you are using `calorieItems`, but you haven't shown where that data comes from. You're also using a `FoodList` class or struct, but not showing what that is. Add a little more code.

Comment: @DonMag just updated my code hopefully it makes things a little more clear

Comment: @Evelyn - It is ***very*** difficult to offer help when the code you post is missing so much information (and is full of errors). Pasting your code, I get 37 errors ranging from `unresolved identifier` to `undeclared type` to `has no member` to `cannot subscript...` to `cannot force unwrap...`. In order to get help, I highly recommend that you define some sample data (so it can run without access to a Firebase server), and get your code to a point where it ***runs*** ... and then get help fixing the data that isn't showing up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using delegates is probably a good idea. I just wrote some code (not tested!) to give you an idea how it could work:

Extend the delegate class:

```
protocol CalculationDelegate: class {
    func onTouchInfoButton(from cell: CalorieFooter)
    func getAdditionalCalories() -> Int
    func getCalculations() -> Int // or whatever type this object should be
}
```

Make sure your view controller follows the protocol:

```
extension CalorieViewController: CalculationDelegate { 
    func onTouchInfoButton(from cell: CalorieFooter) { ... }
    func getAdditionalCalories() -> Int {
        return self.calories
    }
    func getCalculations() -> Int {
        return self.calculations
    }
}
```

Add local variables to `CalorieViewController` that stores the current state (amount of calories/calculations)

```
class CalorieViewController: UIViewController {
    private var calories: Int = 0
    private var calculations: Int = 0

    ... other code that is already in the UIViewController
}
```

Make sure to initialize these variables somewhere! Something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    ... same as before...

    self.calories = subtotal // I guess?
    self.calculations = calculations // put this somewhere where calculations is initialized
}
```

Now, the data should be available in`CalorieFooter`. I added the default values 0 for when the calculationDelegate is `nil`:

```
let calories = calculationDelegate?.getAdditionalCalories() ?? 0
let calculations = calculationDelegate?.getCalculations() ?? 0
```

Good luck!

Comment: it works I just had to do some tweaking to the code it took me a while to figure out how to make the correct connections in the code to make this work

Answer (score 0):

I guess, In viewForFooterInSection() function you forgot to set any value for **calorieFooter.additionalCalories** !

calorieFooter.additionalCalories should be of type DailyCalories not array of DailyCalories.

For example you can set -

```
let date = dateSectionTitle[section]
calorieFooter.additionalCalories = date
```

Without "!" sign, whenever you are assigning some value to any variable you **don't need to use ! in the end**.

Comment: it showing an error code saying "Expression resolves to an unused property" and I knew I didn't put it in but no matter what Ive tried, I kept getting an error code in it